# SQL Server varchar column trying to show line breaks in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssms

I have an ERP solution that saves text inputs into a SQL Server `varchar` column. Users will often include line breaks into these columns.  When I view the data in a SSMS query, the line breaks show as a double space. If I query it in SSRS, the double spaces are removed altogether.

Is it possible to recreate the text column within SSRS, with line breaks directly from a query? (ie replacing double space for a line break)

Example in SSMS

```
Layout Issue Number   Time On  Time Off  Width In   Finished Width   Variations From Layout
```

Same Data in SSRS

```
Layout Issue Number Time On Time OffWidth In Finished Width Variations From Layout
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a few reports where I do essentially this exact thing.  The SQL returns char(10) + char(13) (line feed + carriage return) and SSRS treats that as a line break and carriage return.  My thought for you is to check those two spaces you see in SSMS for what ASCII character they are.  You need both if I recall correctly.  so:

```
select
    ascii(substring('Layout Issue Number   Time On  Time Off  Width In   Finished Width   Variations From Layout',20,1)),
    ascii(substring('Layout Issue Number   Time On  Time Off  Width In   Finished Width   Variations From Layout',21,1))
```

If they return char(32), char(32), you could do replace(string, '  ', char(10)+char(13))

Comment: It returns Char(32) and Char(10).  It returns this value in SSMS and in SSRS.  However in my SSRS report when I add the value to a textbox the carriage return is not present - Just one continual line (where the carriage return was it has removed everything)

Comment: Oh ok.  Well, you can convert that combo of characters to char(10) + char(13) and it should do what you want: replace(@string, char(32)+char(10), char(10)+char(13))

Comment: That doesn't make any difference - it still shows exactly the same in the SSRS text field

Comment: Well in my testing it seems to me SSRS reads char(10) as a line feed and displays it as such in a textbox in a table.  What object type are you putting this data into, is it a textbox in a table or something else?